# Azure Management API access from a web app

Tags: azure, web-applications, azure-active-directory

Is it possible to gain access to the Azure Management APIs through the client ID and secret for a web app?

I have a web app through which i want to be able to manage Azure. I want to do this using the credentials of the application itself so that the current user does not have to be an azure administrator.

I have given the web app the necessary role on my subscriptions and obtained the access token through the client credentials grant flow in AD but i still get an unauthorized.

This is probably because the azure management API has no permission set other than delegated - the access works fine if i use the authorization code grant flow for the logged in user, but thats not what i want.

So to reiterate, if, given a web app that has RBAC to a subscription and is able to obtain an access token from AD, is there any way, without an interactive user, that the web app is able to use the management API??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can obtain a token from AAD for a service principal and use that to manage resources as long as that service principal has all the access you need.

Make sure the token you get has a resource/audience of "https://management.azure.com" and is for the tenantId that the subscription is associated with.

Comment: As far as i am aware, the client ID and secret key for an application in Azure AD forms service principal credentials, which is what i am using with not much luck. I can get the token and the subscription has allowed the web app access but i still get an unauthorized error.

Comment: Specifically this error: The server failed to authenticate the request. Verify that the certificate is valid and is associated with this subscription.

Comment: `As far as i am aware, the client ID and secret key for an application in Azure AD forms service principal credentials` That's not quite true - applications and service principals are separate entities.  Once you've created an application in the portal you can use the `New-AzureRmADServicePrincipal` cmdlet to create a service principal for the application.

Comment: See https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal/

Comment: I still cannot get this to work but from my research so far, including my existing implementation and the above articles, i am concluding that this is the correct way and so will mark as accepted and look elsewhere for why its not working for me

Answer (score 1):

You can also see this article from Brady Gaster that explains how to use Azure AD applications to manage Azure Services from an external app : http://www.bradygaster.com/post/using-windows-azure-active-directory-to-authenticate-the-management-libraries

**EDIT :** Azure AD supports Service to Service calls using OAuth 2.0 client credentials: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn645543.aspx

Hope this helps,

Julien

Comment: Thanks but that article requires interaction to receive the login credentials. I want my web app to be able to access the libraries without an interactive user or, obviously, a popup login dialog either. I want my web app to BE the user.

Comment: I think you can use the OAuth 2.0 client_credentials workflow as explained here : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn645543.aspx + the sample wrote by Brady and you will get what you want :)